# Capture field names in a multiline representation of Django model class

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I need to write a regex expression for vscode extension, which matches fields of the class in a string representation:

```
const str = `
  title = models.CharField(
      blank=True
  )    
  text = models.TextField() 
  author=ForeignKey(
      User,
      on_delete=models.CASCADE
  )
  test_num_10 = models.TextFIeld()
  `
```

from the multiline string bellow I need to capture strings `title, text, author, test_num_10`
Each group follow by a pattern:

- white space
- capturing group, any character
- optional white space
- `=` sign
- optional white space
- any character
- `(` sign
- optional any character
- `)` sign .

So far my regexp looks like this `/\s+(.+)(\s+)?\=(\s+)?.+\((.+)?\).+/`. But it doesn't match what I expect, please help me figure it out.

Comment: For your example data, try it like this [`\s*(.+?)\s*=\s*.+\(([\s\S]*?)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/kGRJU6/1)

Comment: It works. Put this in an answer, so I can thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you example data you could match your values using:

[`\s*(.+?)\s*=\s*.+\(([\s\S]*?)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/kGRJU6/1)

That will match:

- `\s*` Match zero or more times a whitespace character
- `(.+?)` Capture in a group any character zero or more times non greedy
- `\s*` Match zero or more times a whitespace character
- `=` Match literally
- `\s*.+` Match zero or more times a whitespace character followed by any character one or more times
- `\(([\s\S]*?)\)` Between parenthesis capture in a group any character non greedy

Answer (score 1):

Your regex suffers from greediness (all that dot-stars consume up to the end of line then cause a backtrack). You'd better look for a restrictive pattern while there is a chance:

```
(\S+)\s*=\s*[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)
```

- `\S` Matches non-whitespace characters
- `\s` This is the opposite of `\S`
- `[^(]*` Matches anything but an opening parenthesis (optional)
- `[^)]*` Matches anything but a closing parenthesis (optional)

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/O7CHMO/1)